# WPF - Adding a ObjectDataProvider breaks my designer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, triggers, objectdataprovider

Perhaps i'm not using the ObjectDataProvider correctly, but im following the MSDN examples so im not sure whats going wrong.

Goal: When i click a button, it will close the window by calling a method "exitButtonMethod" which simple does this.Close();.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="Window1" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="254" Width="438" Opacity="1" Background="{x:Null}">

<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type local:Window1}"
                  MethodName="exitButtonMethod" x:Key="callExitButtonMethod">
    </ObjectDataProvider>
    <Style x:Key="ExitButtons" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate x:Name="exitButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="exitButtonEllipse" Fill="#597E0000"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="exitButtonEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="#897E0000" />
                            <Binding Source="{StaticResource callExitButtonMethod}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Width="400" Height="200" Opacity="1">
    <Rectangle Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="#FF7E0000" Width="400" RadiusX="40" RadiusY="40" Fill="#64860000" StrokeThickness="3" />
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ExitButtons}" Content="X" Height="25" Width="25" Margin="359,16,16,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Focusable="True" FontSize="15" FontFamily="PMingLiU" Foreground="#FF7E0000" Opacity="1"/>
</Grid>
```

The error is that it simply breaks my designer and gives me the following error in the designer:

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException
[228940] Designer process terminated unexpectedly!
```

Comment: But does your code actually run correctly? I personally have had many terrible experiences with the Visual Studio designer just being bad. It is annoying but if your code works I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: I get a stackoverflow exception at runtime :(

Answer (score 1):

What the purpose of ObjectDataProvider is to create objects in XAML that you can bind to. You can also use it to bind to the results of calling a method on that object, which is what you are trying to do.

Here you are making an **new** object with the type of `Window1` and binding to the method `callExitButtonMethod`. So you are unintentionally making a new window inside your window.

```
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type local:Window1}"
                  MethodName="exitButtonMethod" x:Key="callExitButtonMethod">
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

Now that new window, when created, also has a window inside of it... etc. and you get an infinite loop of making windows.

This is why you are getting a stack overflow.

What you are trying to do is much simpler than what you are currently doing. In order to call a method on a button when you click it, you can simply do:

`<Button Click="NameOfMethodHere" />`

In your case, just add the `Click` parameter to your button and get rid of the `ObjectDataProvider`.

**EDIT:** Also to set events from a Style, see [EventSetter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventsetter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).